# Matrix exponent form

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus

We have  an equation of matrix exponent

$ Ae^{Ax}R-e^{Ax}R (P_1 +P_2 x)  =  Y \tag1$

Given condition

1. $A,R,P_1,P_2,Y$ are constant $3 \times 3 $ matrices.
2. R is invertible,orthonormal,determinent 1(  rotation matrix)
3. x is a scalar variable
4. $P_1,P_2$ skew symmetric,non commutative and non invertible . Same for $P_1 +P_2 x$ .

Question

Could you  find constant matrix A using the given constants in the question satisfying for all x

Thanks